# Combining MySQL AND and OR statements in same query

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's the query I'm currently running:

```
$result = R::getAll("SELECT * FROM vw_participantes_curso JOIN vw_cursos ON vw_participantes_curso.id = vw_cursos.id_curso where LEFT(vw_cursos.sigla, 3) = 'ICV' AND RIGHT(vw_cursos.sigla, 3) = '312' AND username = :u", 
    array(':u' => $username)
);
```

In plain English that query reads:

> Find me a student that is in a course that starts with 'ICV' and ends with '312'.

Now I need to add an or statement inside that same query so it reads:

> Find me a student that is in a course that starts with 'ICV' **and** ends with '312' **and** (has roleid 5 **or** roleid 15).

How do you format nested conditionals like this in MySQL?

Comment: Do it exactly as you have in your pseudocode. Group the two conditions to be OR'd together inside `()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `in` operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM vw_participantes_curso 
JOIN vw_cursos 
ON vw_participantes_curso.id = vw_cursos.id_curso 
where LEFT(vw_cursos.sigla, 3) = 'ICV' 
AND RIGHT(vw_cursos.sigla, 3) = '312' 
AND username = :u
AND roleid in (5,15)
```

or if you really want `or` operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM vw_participantes_curso 
JOIN vw_cursos 
ON vw_participantes_curso.id = vw_cursos.id_curso 
where LEFT(vw_cursos.sigla, 3) = 'ICV' 
AND RIGHT(vw_cursos.sigla, 3) = '312' 
AND username = :u
AND (roleid = 5 or roleid = 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest will be

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE columnName LIKE 'ICV%312' AND
      roleID IN (5,15)
```